# strongloops lb-ng fails in windows

Tags: angularjs, strongloop

I am going through the tutorial [LoopBack/Getting started part II](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Create+AngularJS+client).
Everything is happening as expected until I come to the "Create AngularJS client".
When I try to execute (Windows 7):

> > lb-ng server/server.js client/js/services/lb-services.js

following happens:

```
C:\learn\loopbackLearn>lb-ng server/server.js client/js/services/lb-services.js
Loading LoopBack app "C:\\learn\\loopbackLearn\\server\\server.js"
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'async'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\learn\loopbackLearn\server\boot\create-sample-mode
ls.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

I understand that the fact that the c++ bson extension is missing is just a warning ... but how do I cope with the missing "async" module?

Can you help me?
Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, I had to install async manually before proceed.

`$ npm install async --save`

After this, I got the following error:

Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/action/workspace/github-nodejs/react/loopback-getting-started/client/js/services/lb-services.js'

I created the directory and after this everything worked ok.

```
$ mkdir client/js
$ mkdir client/js/services

$ lb-ng server/server.js client/js/services/lb-services.js
```